# making a variable's type() information immutable

Tags: python

In python, when I use the following code to initialize x:

```
x: int = 42
print(type(x)) # prints <class 'int'>
```

I want to prevent:

```
x = "omg" # should raise "TypeError: x is not of type str" or similar.
x: str = "omg" # should raise "TypeError: x is already defined" or similar.
```

In other words, I want a little optional type safety and declarations added to the language. Is this possible? Are there any PEP discussions about this? Are there any language tools or compiler flags in existence that can do additional type checking?

Comment: Isn't that what MyPy is for?

Comment: No, you can't. Assignment is intrinsic to Python so no way to modify its behavior (add type check, etc.)

Comment: @iBug your comment lead me to this https://pypi.org/project/assign/

Comment: @fht I'm using MyPy as a linter on vs code, but it doesn't warn about global dictionary variables being assigned to different types. Pretty much all linters help with wrong type assigned to methods or function parameters, though.

Comment: @nurettin That sounds like you're probably not typing your dictionary properly then.

Comment: I was just pointing out, like @FHTMitchell did, that you're asking an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). The question in the post is properly solved by linters like MyPy, but this doesn't work for you because the question in the post is not the problem you are having, which is properly typing your dictionary.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt is that still probably or did it now turn into definitely?

Comment: @nurettin Could you clarify what you're asking for?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt you said I probably mistyped some dictionary somewhere (has nothing to do with the question) I said I don't know, and time has passed. Then you gave me a lecture on how to think and  said I did mistype a dictionary. So I'm asking you if "probably mistyped a dictionary" turned into "definitely mistyped a dictionary" and also I'm asking you to drop this conversation because it is getting awkward and I'm also asking you to not start such conversations in the future with others because it is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @nurettin It's not definitively the case that that was the issue, and I wasn't trying to lecture you or ask you for more details or anything. I was just pointing out, for others that find this question such as myself, that the question in the post doesn't match the response in the comments. This way other people don't waste their time being confused as to whether or not MyPy would solve the question posted and if the OP's problems with it are relevant to their needs. As the meta post explains, xy-problems tend to create situations like this that waste everyone's times.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt well you are wrong, I wasn't mistyping anything, mypy at the time had a bug and the response is now irrelevant, so are all your followups.

Answer (score 3):

[PEP 484's "Non Goals" section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals) explicitly says:

> It should also be emphasized that **Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.**

As a dynamically typed language, the "source of truth" for type information will always be the *runtime* (dynamic) type of the object pointed to by a name. The name itself (`x` in this case) **has no type.** It can have a **type hint** that *suggests* what type the values associated with the name will have, but that information is only a *hint*. It's not normative.

The `type()` built-in does not use the type hints at all.

```
x = 'some string'
print(type(x))
```

Will always print `<class 'str'>`, because it's checking the actual *object* that `x` points to, and not anything about `x` itself.

Comment: this is the interesting part in your link: `third party packages would have to be developed to implement specific runtime type checking functionality, for example using decorators or metaclasses.`

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamically typed language, so variables don't have a fixed type. The type annotations you're using can be checked by a tool like mypy (http://mypy-lang.org/) for this sort of type clash but you won't get a runtime error.

On a more technical level, what is stored in `x` is actually a pointer to a data value.
When you call `type(x)`, the interpreter will find the value that `x` points to and will return that value's type.
Python explicitly does not check the type of the value you are assigning to a variable.
From [wiki.python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language):

> In a dynamically typed language, a variable is simply a value bound to a name; the value has a type -- like "integer" or "string" or "list" -- but the variable itself doesn't.